# Why is localStorage getItem displaying only the first item of array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, local-storage, ejs

I'm using localStorage to save checked items on a todo list by converting a div containing fa-check-circle icons into a string using innerHTML, then pushing the results into an array and saving that array into the localStorage. However, I'm having issues making localStorage.getItem() display the saved checks and line-throuh text, it only displays the first one correctly and ignores the rest. The idea was to challenge myself, by make use of localStorage in a different way and so far, the array pushes correctly, the localStorage saves correctly, no errors in the console, but only displays the first one. What am I doing wrong? I feel like maybe I need to grab and display the last key only? This app is tied to mongodb, express backend using ejs if that helps any. I have attached the code, console logs, and the localStorage information below. Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

```
// main.js file

const check = document.querySelectorAll('i.check');
const uncheck = document.querySelectorAll('i.uncheck');
const li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var savedChecks;
var myArr = [];


// Check-off Items 
for(let i = 0; i < uncheck.length; i++) {
    uncheck[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {       
        if(e.target.classList.contains('uncheck')) {
            check[i].className = 'fas fa-check-circle check';
            check[i].style.display = 'block';
            uncheck[i].className = 'fas fa-check-circle check';
            li[i].style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
            editBtn[i].style.display = 'none';


        }
        savedChecks = document.querySelector('.savedList').innerHTML;
        myArr.push(savedChecks);
        localStorage.setItem('checkedItems'+ new Date().getTime(), JSON.stringify(myArr));
    })
};

                   //Code to grab each key and display back to .savedList

    Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function(key){
        document.querySelector('.savedList').innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) || [];
        document.querySelector(".editBtn").innerHTML = '';
        document.querySelector('li').style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
     });
```

```
// EJS code

                <ul id="list">
                        <% for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {%>
                                <li class="list-item">
                                    <span class="savedList"> <!-- Save to localStorage -->
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <span id="circleIcon"><i class="far fa-circle uncheck"></i></span>
                                        <span id="checkIcon"><i class="fas fa-check-circle check"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                                    </span>   

                                    <span class="editText"><%= list[i].item %></span>
                                    <div class="buttons">
                                        <button type="submit" data-update="<%= list[i]._id %>" class="saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                                        <button type="button" onclick="window.location.reload()"class="cancelBtn">X</button>
                                        <button type="button" data-update="<%= list[i]._id %>" class="editBtn"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                                        <button type="button" data-delete="<%= list[i]._id %>" class="delItemBtn"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>   
                                    </div>                
                                </li>  
                        <% } %>
                    </ul>
```

CONSOLE LOG OF THE ARRAY
[console logs of the array -- shows to be saving inside of the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUHKm.png)

CONSOLE LOG OF THE LOCALSTORAGE
[console logs of the localStorage -- shows to be saving inside of the localStorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taijy.png)

LOCALSTORAGE ITSELF SHOWING KEYS SAVED CORRECTLY
[localStorage shows to be saving keys correctly, but will not grab and display correctly?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhWbO.png)

************* UPDATE ************
It appears that this may be not actually be a localStorage issue, but the way I am trying to display the results from the localStorage. I manually added the last key to getItem() and noticed that 2 checks pop up on the same element, so I will try to figure out how to make check localStorage key display on the correct separate elements. Something to do with trying to display in the .savedList element, they are reappearing all in the first element instead of multiple elements as the goal is. I attached a new photo below showing the result of displaying the last key of localStorage....

[image: WHAT THE DISPLAY LOOKS LIKE WHEN LAST KEY IS MANUALLY ADDED TO GETITEM]